# Can a submodule N of a free module M of rank m (over a local principal ideal ring) have a minimal generating set of cardinality larger than m?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a free module of rank $m$ over a local principal ideal ring $R$. Can a submodule $N$ of $M$ have a minimal generating set of cardinality $n>m$?

I found out that Nakayama's lemma imply that every minimal generating set of $N$ have same cardinality. However, I could not find any answer on the relation between the size of minimal generating set of $N$ and the rank of $M$. Proof/counterexample or keywords for googling would be thankful.

Actually, this abstract question arose from the following concrete instantiation. It would be grateful if this can be also answered with proof/counterexample: Can $(\mathbb{Z}_{2^k})^m$ have a subset $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ with $|I|>m$ satisfying: $$\sum_{i\in I}c_iv_i=0 \implies 2|c_i ~~~~~(c_i\in \mathbb{Z}_{2^k})$$

---

Edit: Updated the condition "local ring" to "local principal ideal ring" thanks to @ShiveringSoldier.

Comment: Clearly, $R$ is a free $R$-module of rank $1$. Does that mean every ideal is a principal ideal?

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier Thank you for pointing it out:) I will definitely need stronger notion than "local ring"... What happens if the question is updated to "local principal ideal ring" or "local Artinian principal ideal ring"? I will update the question

Comment: See Theorem 2.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/modulesoverPID.pdf).  The same proof might work in your case. (If it breaks down somewhere, please let me know. At first glance, it seems to me that we don't use the domain hypothesis anywhere in that proof.)

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier It seems to work. I cannot find a part using domain hypothesis in the proof either. So the point was "principal ideal"... Many thanks!